# Binary int to binary char

Tags: c

I am have two variables:

```
int binary[8];
char array;
```

where binary variable have only '0s' and '1s' ... So, I want doing that follow

```
for (i=0;i<8;i++)
    if(binary[i])
        "Here I want put 1 in the position bit of the variable array"
    else
        "Here I want put 0 in the position bit of the variable array"
```

How I will be able to do this?

Comment: Look into the bitwise AND and OR operators. Bitwise negation could help for the latter part as well if you choose to use it.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you right, something like this should work...

```
int binary[8];
char array = 0;

int n = 8;
while (n) {
  array |= binary[--n];
  array <<= 1;
}
```

This should work in any C99-compliant environment where `CHAR_BIT` is at least `8`.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    array |= binary[i] << i;
```